# How to prevent prompt for unsafe attachment?

Tags: vba, outlook, registry

When sending emails with potentially unsafe attachments, Outlook pops up a dialog.

[image]

I'm [programmatically](https://github.com/haphaeu/outlook_mail_fwd) forwarding all my emails to another account and this pop up message is blocking execution of the macro.

There doesn't seem to be a way to prevent the pop-up programmatically, as the `mail.Send` method has no arguments.

```
For Each Item In olFolder.Items
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMail = Item

        If oMail.Permission = olDoNotForward Then
            GoTo for_continue
        End If
                    
        Set objMail = oMail.Forward
        objMail.To = emailTo

        ' this prompts user input in case of unsafe attachments
        objMail.Send 

    End If
for_continue:
Next
```

How to go around this so the macro runs without constant intervention?

Answer (score 0):

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can modify your code as follows. Change the line

```
objMail.Send
```

to

```
dim sItem As Object
sItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
sItem.Item = objMail
sItem.Send
```